# Saving Form API field type "checkboxes" for user_save field

Tags: drupal-7

Thank you for any help you can provide. I am trying to save a new user using user_save(). I have created a custom form and module using Form API, but when I try to save the multiple value checkboxes, the value does not save. Do I need to do something special to save multiple checkbox values of the same form field name?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Basically, you need to loop through the array and make sure your index is specified.

In this example, I created a new user object ($new_user), then iterated through the possible checkbox values. Not the cleanest, but you get the idea.

```
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($form_state['input']['volunteer_select'] as $arr_key => $arr_val) {
      if(!empty($arr_val)) {
        $new_user['field_with_checkboxes'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$counter] = array('value' => $arr_val);
      }
      $counter++;
    }
```